# Need help adding Twitter embedded to HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter

I went to Twitter settings and requested an embedded timeline widget.

It says I just have to add this to the HTML of my website:

```
<a class="twitter-timeline" href="https://twitter.com/TwitterDev">Tweets by TwitterDev</a> <script async src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

However, when I add it to my HTML, only the link "Tweets by TwitterDev" shows and the rest of the twitter timeline does not show AT ALL.

Here is a similar picture to show what I mean
[image]

What did I do wrong?

Comment: You need to add more than that, this will just add a link to your website and redirect you to twitter dev profile.

Comment: Open This  link https://dev.twitter.com/web/javascript/loading and follow the steps under (*Create an Embedded Timeline). Hope this will help you

Comment: @shishir yes it worked. Thank you!